# How to remove tab from TabHost

Tags: android, android-widget

In a [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) widget, I can create a new tab with its content (Intent) using [TabHost.addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#addTab(android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec)).

We can remove all tabs we created by calling [clearAllTabs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#clearAllTabs()), but I can't figure out how to remove the tab or just replace the content (Intent) inside the tab with new Intent.

so what I need something like `removeTab(int index)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, clearAllTabs does that :

```
public void clearAllTabs() {
  mTabWidget.removeAllViews();
  initTabHost();
  mTabContent.removeAllViews();
  mTabSpecs.clear();
  requestLayout();
  invalidate();
}
```

And the method removeAllViews comes from the class `ViewGroup`. Luckily, `ViewGroup` does have methods to remove only one view :

- `removeView(View  view)`
- `removeViewAt(int index)`
- `removeViewInLayout(View view)`

Knowing that, I would recommend to subclass `TabWidget` and `TabHost` to add the behaviour you need. Maybe there is an easier way but that's the only one I can think of.
Good luck

Answer (score 25):

Much Easier:

```
 tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3));
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking 4.

Comment: can tab be remove by its tag or able to find the current index position of tab click..

Comment: current index: tabHost.getCurrentTab()

Comment: I am using `FragmentTabHost` and when I am debugging after removing particular tab, it is still showing in the list of tabs but not visible, this is making me when I am pressing tab at removed position showing me removed fragment data, which is exceptionally weird!!