# Android TabActivity - Unable to resume activity; onResume() method & NullPointerException

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, tabactivity

I've got an interesting Android developing problem.
I use TabActivity (I know it's deprecated) in my app which makes it possible to choose and navigate between 3 tabs (manual and automatic processing, and configuration tab; the main goal of the application is not relevant now).

Few days ago I tested the application on other kind of devices: on an Alcatel phone, do not remember the exact type; before that on a Samsung Galaxy S4, and other, older Samsung devices; still, there was a no-name chinese Android tablet as well. **None of these devices had a problem with TabActivity.**

But now, today I've tried to use the application on a Samsung Galaxy S2 and on an HTC Desire S, and **both devices have crashed 'cause of using TabActivity**.

To make it easier to imagine the GUI: three tabs, the third one is a menu with some submenus. Navigating between the three basic tabs doesn't make any problem. BUT: if I go on the third tab into one of the submenus, and then try coming back to the menu (implemented, or physical 'Back' button, doesn't matter), the application **crashes**.

The error messages are the following:

```
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.MY_PROJECT/com.example.MY_PROJECT.ControlActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2571)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2592)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1080)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.widget.TabWidget.setCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:344)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.widget.TabWidget.focusCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:368)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at com.example.MY_PROJECT.ControlActivity.setTabs(ControlActivity.java:186)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at com.example.MY_PROJECT.ControlActivity.onResume(ControlActivity.java:160)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1242)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4004)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2561)
08-21 09:46:18.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7781):     ... 10 more
```

Some Java code that could be important:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        Resources res = getResources();
        this.setTitle(res.getString(R.string.title_activity_main_menu));
        mTabHost.clearAllTabs();
        setTabs();
        MainActivity.isAnotherDevSel = false;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initial(); //Initializing variables
        mTabHost = getTabHost();
        setTabs();
    }

    public void setTabs() {

        tempPos = position;
        Resources res = getResources();
        tabspecAutoTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("auto")
                .setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.title_pagecontname))
                .setContent(new Intent(ControlActivity.this, AutoTab.class));
        tabspecManualTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("manual")
                .setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.title_pagemanname))
                .setContent(new Intent(ControlActivity.this, ManualTab.class));
        tabspecConfigTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("config")
                .setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.title_pageconfname))
                .setContent(new Intent(ControlActivity.this, ConfigTab.class));

        mTabHost.addTab(tabspecAutoTab);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabspecManualTab);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabspecConfigTab);

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                if ("auto".equals(tabId)) {
                    ManualTab.isManualInfo = false;
                    position = 0;
                }

                else if ("manual".equals(tabId)) {
                    AutoTab.isAutoInfo = false;
                    position = 1;
                }

                if ("config".equals(tabId)
                        && (AutoTab.isAutoRunning || ManualTab.isManualRunning)) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            ControlActivity.this);

                    alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.running_program);

                    alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.not_use_config);

                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {

                                    if (AutoTab.isAutoRunning) {
                                        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                                    } else if (ManualTab.isManualRunning) {
                                        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    AlertDialog alertDialogBuilder = alertDialog.create();

                    alertDialogBuilder.show();
                }
            }
        });

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(tempPos);
    }
```

Tried to find similar questions but I wasn't successful.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance. :)

Best regards,
Zs

**Debug window**:

```
<terminated>MY_PROJECT [Android Application]    
    <disconnected>DalvikVM[localhost:8600]  
MY_PROJECT [Android Application]    
    DalvikVM[localhost:8600]    
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
            <VM does not provide monitor information>   
            TabWidget.setCurrentTab(int) line: 344  
            TabWidget.focusCurrentTab(int) line: 368    
            TabHost.setCurrentTab(int) line: 323    
            TabHost.addTab(TabHost$TabSpec) line: 216   
            ControlActivity.setTabs() line: 211 
            ControlActivity.onResume() line: 160    
            Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Activity) line: 1242   
            ControlActivity(Activity).performResume() line: 4004    
            ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(IBinder, boolean) line: 2561   
            ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(IBinder, boolean, boolean) line: 2592   
            BinderProxy(ActivityThread$H).handleMessage(Message) line: 1080 
            ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
            Looper.loop() line: 150 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4385    
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 849  
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 607 
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
        Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
        Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
        Thread [<10> AsyncTask #1] (Running)    
        Thread [<11> Binder Thread #3] (Running)    
        Thread [<12> Thread-12] (Running)   

setTabs():

    this    ControlActivity  (id=830007806776)  
    address "00:14:03:18:68:92" (id=830007826024)   
    bluetoothAdapter    BluetoothAdapter  (id=830008015408) 
    btDevice    BluetoothDevice  (id=830008071648)  
    btMessage   "0/ 3.52/ 0.00\r" (id=830007771352) 
    bundle  Bundle  (id=830008071800)   
    dsm DefaultSettingsManager  (id=830008395608)   
    handler ControlActivity$1  (id=830007939176)    
    isNotInFront    true    
    mActivity_dispatchPenEvent  null    
    mActivity_onPenEvent    null    
    mActivityInfo   ActivityInfo  (id=830008207600) 
    mApplication    Application  (id=830007937232)  
    mBase   ContextImpl  (id=830008089024)  
    mBase   ContextImpl  (id=830008089024)  
    mCalled true    
    mComponent  ComponentName  (id=830008207352)    
    mConfigChangeFlags  0   
    mCurrentConfig  Configuration  (id=830008198384)    
    mDecor  PhoneWindow$DecorView  (id=830008078448)    
    mDefaultKeyMode 0   
    mDefaultKeySsb  null    
    mDefaultTab null    
    mDefaultTabIndex    -1  
    mEmbeddedID null    
    mExecuteFastLaunch  false   
    mFinished   false   
    mHandler    Handler  (id=830008065464)  
    mIdent  1082549496  
    mInflater   PhoneLayoutInflater  (id=830008198232)  
    mInstrumentation    Instrumentation  (id=830007792592)  
    mIntent Intent  (id=830008207200)   
    mLastNonConfigurationChildInstances null    
    mLastNonConfigurationInstance   null    
    mLocalActivityManager   LocalActivityManager  (id=830007825000) 
    mMainThread ActivityThread  (id=830007781896)   
    mManagedCursors ArrayList  (id=830008207176)    
    mManagedDialogs null    
    mMenuSize   0   
    mParent null    
    mResultCode 0   
    mResultData null    
    mResumed    true    
    mSearchManager  null    
    mStartedActivity    false   
    mStopped    false   
    mTabHost    TabHost  (id=830008193424)  
    mTheme  Resources$Theme  (id=830008073688)  
    mThemeResource  2131427447  
    mTitle  " (id=830007786896)" (id=830007786896)  
    mTitleColor 0   
    mTitleReady true    
    mToken  BinderProxy  (id=830008207544)  
    mUiThread   Thread  (id=830002591192)   
    mVisibleFromClient  true    
    mVisibleFromServer  false   
    mWindow PhoneWindow  (id=830008199768)  
    mWindowAdded    true    
    mWindowManager  Window$LocalWindowManager  (id=830008089384)    
    MY_UUID UUID  (id=830008067000) 
    progressDialog  ProgressDialog  (id=830007765240)   
    releaseMemoryRunnable   Activity$1  (id=830007961136)   
    res Resources  (id=830007936080)    
    tabspecAutoTab  TabHost$TabSpec  (id=830008573904)  
    tabspecConfigTab    TabHost$TabSpec  (id=830008574224)  
    tabspecManualTab    TabHost$TabSpec  (id=830008574064)  
    tempPos 2   
    res Resources  (id=830007936080)    

onResume():

    this    ControlActivity  (id=830007806776)  
    address "00:14:03:18:68:92" (id=830007826024)   
    bluetoothAdapter    BluetoothAdapter  (id=830008015408) 
    btDevice    BluetoothDevice  (id=830008071648)  
    btMessage   "0/ 3.52/ 0.00\r" (id=830007771352) 
    bundle  Bundle  (id=830008071800)   
    dsm DefaultSettingsManager  (id=830008395608)   
    handler ControlActivity$1  (id=830007939176)    
    isNotInFront    true    
    mActivity_dispatchPenEvent  null    
    mActivity_onPenEvent    null    
    mActivityInfo   ActivityInfo  (id=830008207600) 
    mApplication    Application  (id=830007937232)  
    mBase   ContextImpl  (id=830008089024)  
    mBase   ContextImpl  (id=830008089024)  
    mCalled true    
    mComponent  ComponentName  (id=830008207352)    
    mConfigChangeFlags  0   
    mCurrentConfig  Configuration  (id=830008198384)    
    mDecor  PhoneWindow$DecorView  (id=830008078448)    
    mDefaultKeyMode 0   
    mDefaultKeySsb  null    
    mDefaultTab null    
    mDefaultTabIndex    -1  
    mEmbeddedID null    
    mExecuteFastLaunch  false   
    mFinished   false   
    mHandler    Handler  (id=830008065464)  
    mIdent  1082549496  
    mInflater   PhoneLayoutInflater  (id=830008198232)  
    mInstrumentation    Instrumentation  (id=830007792592)  
    mIntent Intent  (id=830008207200)   
    mLastNonConfigurationChildInstances null    
    mLastNonConfigurationInstance   null    
    mLocalActivityManager   LocalActivityManager  (id=830007825000) 
    mMainThread ActivityThread  (id=830007781896)   
    mManagedCursors ArrayList  (id=830008207176)    
    mManagedDialogs null    
    mMenuSize   0   
    mParent null    
    mResultCode 0   
    mResultData null    
    mResumed    true    
    mSearchManager  null    
    mStartedActivity    false   
    mStopped    false   
    mTabHost    TabHost  (id=830008193424)  
    mTheme  Resources$Theme  (id=830008073688)  
    mThemeResource  2131427447  
    mTitle  " (id=830007786896)" (id=830007786896)  
    mTitleColor 0   
    mTitleReady true    
    mToken  BinderProxy  (id=830008207544)  
    mUiThread   Thread  (id=830002591192)   
    mVisibleFromClient  true    
    mVisibleFromServer  false   
    mWindow PhoneWindow  (id=830008199768)  
    mWindowAdded    true    
    mWindowManager  Window$LocalWindowManager  (id=830008089384)    
    MY_UUID UUID  (id=830008067000) 
    progressDialog  ProgressDialog  (id=830007765240)   
    releaseMemoryRunnable   Activity$1  (id=830007961136)   
    res Resources  (id=830007936080)    
    tabspecAutoTab  TabHost$TabSpec  (id=830008573904)  
    tabspecConfigTab    TabHost$TabSpec  (id=830008574224)  
    tabspecManualTab    TabHost$TabSpec  (id=830008574064)  
    tempPos 2   
    res Resources  (id=830007936080)
```

Comment: your error is in ControlActivity.java line  number 186. please check what you are trying to access at this line

Comment: what is the value of `tempPos`?

Comment: Line 186: mTabHost.addTab(tabspecAutoTab);

Comment: tempPos <- position variable's value which is 0 because of initial method. Changing when tab is changing, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 11 hours research, trying, work and suffering the answer found here:
[Removing a tab and the activity (intent) inside of it from a TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157373/removing-a-tab-and-the-activity-intent-inside-of-it-from-a-tabhost)

(A lot of thanks to **wired00**)

The following line was needed in the onResume() method:

```
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

right before:

```
mTabHost.clearAllTabs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code for initializing tab intent to

```
    tabspecAutoTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("auto")
            .setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.title_pagecontname))
            .setContent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AutoTab.class));
    tabspecManualTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("manual")
            .setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.title_pagemanname))
            .setContent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManualTab.class));
    tabspecConfigTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("config")
            .setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.title_pageconfname))
            .setContent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConfigTab.class));
```

Comment: The onCreate() method has initialized it by the way.

Comment: Yep. :) AutoTab gone, and coming back to the menu (on the 3rd tab) still kills the app.

Comment: Nope. Logged it twice, wasn't ever null.

Comment: Tried (changed code all 3 times) and still got the error. :/

Comment: Logged both before tabspecAutoTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("auto")... lines and addTab methods: wasn't ever null.

Comment: Than please use debugger to find out the correct null object.

Comment: Here's a picture about the Debugger:
http://postimg.org/image/ywlsksr01/

It's really odd: check the right side of the window. I could open those "cause" things forever.

Comment: Second picture (debugging continued): http://postimg.org/image/uehgv39sd/

And here it's over.

Comment: I can not check any picture here as the site is blocked. Please check which object is null.

Comment: I've put some information from debug window into the original post.