# How to remove tabspec from FragmentTabHost?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a Fragment, in that, i declare a FragmentTabHost.

```
public class ComFragment extends Fragment{

    ...
    private FragmentTabHost mTabhost;
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        return mTabhost;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.com_tabhost, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ...
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_clear:

            break;
        case R.id.action_close:
            int index = mTabhost.getCurrentTab();
            /*\ How can i remove current tab at here?*/
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I remove current tabspec when i click on item?

Comment: can you share screenshot , which item you want to delete

Comment: I have added some TabSpecs to mTabhost. Now, I want, when i click on an MenuItem, current TabSpec will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no way of accessing the `TabSpec` once you add it to the `FragmentTabHost`. You'll have to define some datastructure (probably a `Map` or derivate) in your class where you store the `TabSpec`s for each tab, and when you want to remove one, you'll have to call `.clearAllTabs()` on your `FragmentTabHost` and loop your `Map` to add again all `TabSpec`s except the one you want to remove.

Comment: I have refered follow this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299845/how-to-remove-tab-from-tabhost
I tried: mTabhost.getTabWidget().removeView(mTabhost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(index));
But it throw null pointer exception.

Comment: Both `TabHost` and `FragmentTabHost` comes tricky when removing individual tabs from them. The question you've followed is just the first step (removing all the tabs), but afterwards you have to restore the ones you want to keep, thus you'll have to store the `TabSpec`s somewhere and handle it the way I wrote.